# How to upload an empty folder to S3 using Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, backup

My program backs up all the files in the directory, except for empty folders. How do you upload an empty folder into S3 using Boto 3, Python?

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(path):
    # for each directory, walk through all files
    for fname in fileList:

        current_key = dirName[dir_str_index:] +"\\"+ fname
        current_key = current_key.replace("\\", "/")
```

Answer (score 2):

[S3 doesn't really have folders](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html):

> Amazon S3 has a flat structure instead of a hierarchy like you would see in a file system. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this by using a shared name prefix for objects (that is, objects that have names that begin with a common string).

Since folders are just part of object names,  you can't have empty folders in S3.